# Wit.ai: search strategy options

Tags: wit.ai

There are three search strategies for own entities: `trait`, `free-text` and `keywords`, as [explained in the documentation](https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#which-entity-should-i-use).
What I can't understand, is the allowed combinations of these options. I am able to choose either:

- `trait`
- `keywords`
- `free-text` and `keywords`

Why can't free-text be chosen on it's own, only in combination with `keywords`?

**Edit:**

Definition of `free-text`, from the documentation:

> When you need to extract a substring of the message, and this
>   substring does not belong to a predefined list of possible values.

Definition of `keywords`:

> When the entity value belongs to a predefined list, and you just need
>   substring matching to look it up in the sentence.

From the definition, `free-text` and `keywords` look mutually exclusive to me. Therefore I can't understand why I can't choose `free-text` on its own, and why it is possible to choose both simultaneously.

Comment: How should free text be parsed without keywords?

Answer (score 0):

I think solution in the word 'extract' in free-text and 'matching' in keywords, cause in case of free-text it extract substring from message but this substring has to have some words matches with original message.

in this example there is '**i will be**' mutual with all messages, so we need both free-text to extract and keyword to match.
  [image]